# Javascript : Posting a request and then redirecting the page to another page

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a use case where i have to post the form data on a particular link and then forward/redirect the request to another link.
For e.g. In my page i have 3 textfields a,b,c and a submit button. On click of Submit i will post the request to say "http://www.abc.com/example" and then redirect the request to "http://www.def.com".

So for the end user after submitting the request he/she will see "http://www.def.com" and will not come to know that what happened in between.

We do not care what the response is from server where request is posted.

Any help/directions in implementing this use case will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Regards,
Mayank

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the submit URL in form's `action`.

```
<form action="http://www.abc.com/example" method="post">
```

and let the code behind that URL redirect the request to the desired URL after postprocessing the request; the following example assumes that it's using the Servlet API:

```
response.sendRedirect("http://www.def.com");
```

No need for JavaScript here which would not work anyway on JS-disabled clients.

Answer (score 0):

It would be preferable for performance to submit the form to your original server and then redirect to the other URL.

If you can't do this, then you could submit the request via AJAX request and on completion (success or error) change the window.location to the other URL.